# How to change line properties in ggplot2 halfway in a time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart

Take the following straightforward plot of two time series from the `economics{ggplot2}` dataset

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(lubridate)
require(tidyr)

economics %>%
  gather(indicator, percentage, c(4:5), -c(1:3, 6)) %>%
  mutate(Y2K = year(date) >= 2000) %>%
  group_by(indicator, Y2K) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, percentage, group = indicator, colour = indicator)) + geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

I would like to change the `linetype` from "solid" to "dashed" (and possibly also the line `size`) for all points in the 21st century, i.e. for those observations for which `Y2K` equals `TRUE`.

I did a `group_by(indicator, Y2K)` but inside the `ggplot` command it appears I cannot use `group =` on multiple levels, so the line properties only differ by `indicator` now.

**Question**: How can I achieve this segmented line appearance?

**UPDATE**: my preferred solution is a slight tweak from the one by @sahoang:

```
economics %>%
        gather(indicator, percentage, c(4:5), -c(1:3, 6)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(date, percentage, colour = indicator)) + 
        geom_line(size=1, aes(linetype = year(date) >= 2000)) +
        scale_linetype(guide = F)
```

This eliminates the `group_by` as commented by @Roland, and the `filter` steps make sure that the time series will be connected at the Y2K point (in case the data would be year based, there could be a visual discontinuity otherwise).

Comment: You don't need to map to `group` at all. You simply need an additional grouping variable that `linetype` is mapped to. Possibly you need to duplicate points where the switch occurs. Can't help you more since `dplyr` isn't to my taste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even easier than @Roland's suggestion:

```
economics %>%
    gather(indicator, percentage, c(4:5), -c(1:3, 6)) %>%
    mutate(Y2K = year(date) >= 2000) %>%
    group_by(indicator, Y2K) -> econ

ggplot(econ, aes(date, percentage, group = indicator, colour = indicator)) + 
  geom_line(data = filter(econ, !Y2K), size=1, linetype = "solid") + 
  geom_line(data = filter(econ, Y2K), size=1, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

P.S. Alter plot width to remove spike artifacts (red line).

Answer (score 4):

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(lubridate)
require(tidyr)


economics %>%
  gather(indicator, percentage, c(4:5), -c(1:3, 6)) %>%
  mutate(Y2K = year(date) >= 2000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, percentage, colour = indicator)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, aes(linetype = Y2K))
```

Comment: thanks, but I accept the answer from @tonytonov because it does not create a separate legend for the linetype.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the linetype legend you can add scale_linetype(guide = F).